# How to invoke SOAP Webservice using Power Automate / MS Flow

Tags: web-services, powerapps, power-automate

## Problem Statement

Need to build a Power APP which invokes a SOAP Webservice and displays the response on the Power APP.
It also involves taking input frmo the user from POwer APP screen and persisting using a SOAP Webservice.

### Query:

> 1. Does Power Automate provide a Connector via which we can invoke a SOAP Webservice? If yes, could you please provide a sample/ references to retrieve results from the Webservice and pass it to Power App.
>
> > 2. If not, then how can we invoke SOAP Webservice via MS Flow/ Power Automate?

Answer (score 4):

1. There is not a "ready to use" connector for SOAP
2. You have the ability to create custom connector to fulfil your needs

Here are some steps that you could perform to achieve that - the steps are from @clavinfernandes [link to his blog post](https://clavinfernandes.wordpress.com/2019/11/01/soap-custom-connectors-in-microsoft-flow/)

1. Get Postman
2. Create a collection in Postman
3. Configu Postman to use your SOAP endpoint
4. Save the request - test it
5. Export the collection (Collection V1) - that will be a json file

When done you can create the Custom Connector from the Power Automate page:

1. Open Power Automate site
2. Under Data, choose Custom connectors
3. - New Custom connector -> Import a postman collection (V1)
4. Review the info from your exported collection and fill in the general information popup
5. Configure the Authentication type and then review the definitions
6. Then click Create connector

You should be able to use that within your flows now:

1. Create a new flow and choose a trigger (Power Apps trigger in your case I believe)
2. Add you connector and configure it with the correct properties
3. You can use a combination of the Compose action with the Xpath expression to get information from the XML that is returned by your call.
4. Use the "Respond to a PowerApp or flow" action to pass the information back to your App

I hope that helps you